# Selecting and Deselecting multiple options from list without keyboard

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have the following list that is present to the user

```
<select id="regions" multiple="multiple">
  <option value='us-west' selected="selected">US West Coast</option>
  <option value='us-east' selected="selected">US East Coast</option>
  <option value='eur' selected="selected">Europe</option>
  <option value='asia' selected="selected">Asia</option>
</select>
```

As shown above, all items are selected.

I was trying to implement a jquery function where if the user clicks an option on the list only the clicked item (let's say Europe) will be removed, while the rest of the options are selected. I know that this is possible by holding down "CTRL" and clicking, but is there a way where all the user has to do is to click?

I tried this function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function(){
        $("#regions options:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: How are you going to call that anonymous function with no identifier?

Comment: That was an error from my part, I added the $('#regions option'), still no change.

Answer (score 1):

So it took me a while, but I think I have the functionality you're looking for.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JUSx/3/)

The idea is, create an array to keep track of what's selected. The natural behaviour of a multiple select box if you only click, is to deselect all other selections and select what you clicked on.

Therefore, instead of being concerned with what's in the selectbox, we see which option is clicked on (on mousedown) and add it to our personal list of what's selected, then update the select box to reflect whats in our list (on mouseup).

This prevents the user from dragging to select multiple items in the selectbox, but being able to do that would probably just mess it up.

```
var selection = [];

$('#the_box > option').mousedown(function(){

    if(selection.length < 1){
        selection.push($(this).val());
    } else {
        var found = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
            if(selection[i] == $(this).val()){
                selection.splice(i, 1);
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found === 0){
            selection.push($(this).val());
        }
    }
});

$('#the_box').bind('mouseup mouseout', function(){
    $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    });
    $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        for(i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
            if($(this).val() == selection[i]){
                $(this).attr('selected','selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You would however, be able to do this exact thing with just a list or set of divs, instead of using the native `<select>` tags, which would actually be easier if you're using this method (due to not having to work around the default behavior of the selectbox) :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('option').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('selected', 'selected')
    .siblings().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

What this function does, is to remove current selection state of the clicked item, but re-selecting the entire **siblings** set.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/fVGNa/).

**Update:** Since by using keyboard, we can send another signal (another flag) to the control, we still need to simulate it somehow using mouse. We can for example assume that right-click is like Ctrl+click and left click is simply a click. However, right-click is not a good pattern in web and not that common.

Another option could be to redefine our business to make the control behave differently (for example, on mouse click, if the object is already selected, then deselect it, and if it's not selected, add it to the whole collection of selected options). But the disadvantage of this approach is that users get lost when using your control, because it gets far from normal HTML controls with which they have interaction on a daily basis. In other words, changing the behavior of a control is not a good solution regarding UX.

Comment: That looks great. Except it looks like as if it is refreshing the whole list, which will make the AJAX go ballistic. Would you recommend a cleaner option? I was hoping to use checkbox, but mgmt considers that as something "ugly"

Comment: I think he's looking for a way to select multiple items without using the keyboard. Test your fiddle, this isn't possible with your solution.

Comment: But not without mouse. I used `click` handler, not `keyup`.

Comment: The problem is the normal behavior of multiple selects. We'll need to know whether or not it was selected before you click it, because the click itself will clear the other selections

Comment: All the options were selected on pageload. The information is sent to a graph generator. From what I see in the fiddle, when I click on an item to deselect, it deselects all item and then immediately imposes the change of the user (such as deselecting Europe while keeping the rest of the options active, as an example). I am afraid that method would break the graph generator if we are dealing with a lot of records.

Comment: I just realized what you suggested doesn't fully do what it's supposed to. For example, if I deselect Europe, and then I deselect Asia, Europe will be selected again.

Comment: That's what I was talking about :D

Comment: I just had a "whoosh" moment for myself :P

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the perfect solution but you are welcome to try it.

To attach the function (note that this allows a callback function to be fired after selecting items .. for example if you want to populate another list based on the selection)

```
$('#mySelect').click(function () {
    singleClickList(this, myCallbackFunction);
});
```

The function:

```
function singleClickList(mythis, callback) {
    var selected = $(mythis).data('selected');
    if (selected == undefined) selected = [];
    var scrollTop = mythis.scrollTop;
    var current = $(mythis).val();
    var index;
    if (current != null) {
        if (current.length > 0) {
            index = $.inArray(current[0], selected);
            if (index >= 0)
                selected.splice(index, 1);
            else
                selected.push(current[0]);
        }
        $(mythis).val(selected);
        $(mythis).data('selected', selected);
        mythis.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        if (callback) callback();
    }
}
```

Note that this requires jquery, and makes use of the jquery .data method to store the array of selected items.